# SAP Business One integration with Magento

Tags: magento, sapb1

Is there any open source solutions available to integrate SAP Business One with Magento? I am aware about http://www.sboeconnect.com/ but was hoping if there is some other open source library that does this.

Comment: I have never heard of one...  One option is to contact the people at http://www.ebridgeconnections.com/.  Magento offers the "Bridge Connect" for the EE version, however after actually calling eBridge, it doesn't seem like EE is needed.  SAP is on the list of connectivity options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SAP in itself is a commercial (non-free) product, so any integrations of other applications (like Magento or any CRM) with SAP will unlikely be available at free of cost.

As far as [SBOeConnect](http://www.sboeconnect.com/) is concerned, it provides one of the best supports as compared to other products related with SAP & Magento.

Hope it helps.